# ido-find-file: typing "//" triggers loading of tramp

Tags: hooks, ido-find-file

When using ``` M-x``ido-find-file ``` and typing "//" via keyboard in the minibuffer, some hook or function is triggered which starts loading the `tramp` package.

**Which `tramp` function is triggered and how to get this information?**
(in case there is more which gets triggered)

Note: this is my use-package definition of tramp:

```
(use-package tramp
    :defer t
    :config
    (message "tramp-loaded"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the relevant things to look at are:

- `tramp-file-name-regexp` which defines expressions to match file names that tramp should handle.
- `tramp-register-autoload-file-name-handlers` which registers tramp to handle file names that match the specified patterns.

I haven't looked at this in detail, but I believe tramp registers handlers to complete / handle file names, so when you try to complete a path matching one of the defined expressions, tramp gets loaded.

Specifically, I think the following code in tramp.el causes the file handlers to be registered before tramp itself is loaded:

```
;;;###autoload
(tramp-register-autoload-file-name-handlers)
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that `tramp-completion-file-name-handler` and `tramp-autoload-file-name-handler` trigger loading of tramp. Both are registered in `file-name-handler-alist`. I wonder how they got into this alist if tramp has not been loaded before ...

Comment: Tramp's file handlers are registered using the `autoload` functionality. Search for `tramp` in `M-x find-library RET loaddefs.el RET`